# Need to change TD background via after a function is executed

Tags: jquery, hover, row, html-table

I have a script that works great for changing the TR and TD background of my table when a condition is met.

But the CSS background hover does not work for those rows.

Is there a way to keep my background change via hover work for these rows?

Here is my current CSS that does work for rows that are not affected by the conditional function.

```
table.tablesorterPRINT  tr.odd:hover td {background-color: #6F0;cursor:pointer;}
```

Erik

```
if(qty<=min) { $(this).parent('tr').children('td').css('background' , 'red').css('color' , '#FFF');}
if(qty>=max) { $(this).parent('tr').children('td').css('background' , 'red').css('background' , '#FFF'); }
```

Comment: Why are you using `css` method twice: `css('background' , 'red').css('color' , '#FFF');`, it will apply the latter color anyway in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the background color via JavaScript, the new style is applied by the `style` attribute on the element.

The `style` attribute takes precedence over the definitions from a `class` or `id`.

What you need to do, is to set the `:hover` with an `!important` notation, to tell the browser that no mater what, that is the `hover` style you want.

```
table.tablesorterPRINT  tr.odd:hover td {
  background-color: #6F0!important;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to the `:hover` property to force it to override the inline style.

Or, better yet, use a class instead of a style:

```
tr.BadRow td {
    background: red;
}

$(this).parent().addClass('BadRow');
```